# Загрузить изображение png в Image из БД SQL (Delphi)

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, delphi-7

Такая проблема.Облазил весь инет ничего не могу найти.
Как загрузить в Image картинку из Базы данных SQL.
Вот выбор картинки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Тип столба картинки  MediumBlob

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
uses
  PNGImage;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  VPng: TGraphic;
begin
  VPng := TPNGObject.Create; // или TPNGImage.Create; если Delphi XE2 и выше
  try
    ...
    SQLQuery1.Open;

    VPng.Assign(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('photo'));
    Image1.Picture.Assign(VPng);
  finally
    VPng.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Компонент PNGImage в новых версиях Delphi встроен, а для старых версий можно взять тут: https://github.com/JackTrapper/pngdelphi

---

Альтернативный способ, через промежуточный TStream:

```
var      
  VPng: TGraphic;
  VStream: TStream;
begin
  VPng := TPNGObject.Create;
  try
    ...
    SQLQuery1.Open;

    VStream := SQLQuery1.CreateBlobStream(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('photo'), bmRead);
    try
      // тут VStream можно сохранить на диск или сделать 
      // какие-то дополнительные проверки формата изображения

      VPng.LoadFromStream(VStream);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(VPng);
    finally
      VStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    VPng.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку! Profet raised exception class EPNGInvalidFileHeader with message the file being read is not a valid portable network Graphics image becaus it constains an invalid header.This file may be corrupted, try obtaining it again

Comment: @Program_Casual Ошибка говорит о том, что загруженное изображение не является PNG изображением. Возможно, у вас там jpeg?

Comment: Дополнил ответ альтернативным методом.

Comment: Я загрузил jpeg, ошибка та же. Ваш альтернативный метод не сработал.

Comment: @Program_Casual Надо было загрузить png. Оба метода рабочие, так что ищите ошибку у себя.

Comment: Все заработало, большое спасибо!Воспользовался 2 способом. Курсач спасен :)